# How to deal with suspicious sudo user?

Tags: ubuntu, security

I am running *Ubuntu 14.04 server* with *ISPConfig* installed and etc.

Latest I saw a suspicious home directory named **ub**. It has some encrypted files in it. Also I found `/run/shm/ecryptfs-ub-Private` is owned by this user.

I changed password of the user and ssh login to the account. Just saw encrypted files. Later on I deleted the user **ub** and group **ub**. But I am not sure if I have done the right thing.

Does it might be a auto generated user and group by some services? Or is it really suspicious?

I did not see any processes run by this user by `top` command.

Comment: what does the logs say?

Comment: in auth.log I did not see any logins for ub. in dmesg no interesting result for seach "ub ". in syslog for latest logs I did not find anything either. created home directory has a old modified time, it is march 14, 2015. I may not notice it, I seldomly check /home directory.

Comment: Also I checked my mails. That was the exact date when I moved to a new server and asked help from datacenter. They might create it, for support. I will ask them. Thanks.

Comment: @bkilinc That could explain it. Is it a managed server?

Comment: no it isn't, but on that date, they installed the server as Virtual Machine, using their ISO files. Also they made some network configuration. Also I remember, buying hourly paid support. Thanks for help.